# Почему статическая доступность позволяет выполнять сравнение с помощью оператора сравнения ссылок ==?

Tags: java

[В одной статье](http://www.quizful.net/post/java_enums) наткнулась на следующие строки:

> Элементы enum Season (WINTER, SPRING и т.д.) - это статически
>   доступные экземпляры enum-класса Season. Их статическая доступность
>   позволяет нам выполнять сравнение с помощью оператора сравнения ссылок
>   ==.

А каким образом статическая доступность позволяет выполнять сравнение с помощью оператора сравнения ссылок `==`? Почему нестатические объекты сравнивать через `==` нельзя, а статические можно?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

При сравнению через `==` сравниваются указатели, а статические поля класса одинаковы для всех экземпляров класса - указатели на них определяются в момент запуска программы. Если поле финальное, то оно не изменяется на протяжении всей работы программы. А элементы `enum` как раз финальные (в вашей ссылке далее по тексту приводится пример декомпиляции `enum`-а - это класс с `public static final` полями).

> Почему нестатические объекты сравнивать через == нельзя, а статические можно?

Неизменяемость указателей статических полей и позволяет их сравнивать.

Примерным аналогом `enum` может служить следующий класс ("примерным", т.к. для полноты соответствия нужно также реализовать методы `valueOf`, `values`):

```
public class Season {
    public static final Season WINTER = new Season();
    public static final Season SPRING = new Season();
    public static final Season SUMMER = new Season();
    public static final Season AUTUMN = new Season();

    private Season() {}
}
Season a = Season.AUTUMN;
Season b = Season.AUTUMN;
System.out.println(a == b); //true
```